# content has lower-case or not in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can we check In PostgreSQL or SQL:

A string saved in database to lowercase OR uppercase?

For example, I have five records in my database table and I want to fetch only  those records that have lowercase characters.

Here is my content table and id's in primary key

```
id    Content

 1     TEST
 2     Test
 3     TEst
 4     TESt
 5     TEST01
```

I need to fetch id 2,3,4 respectively which contains context value in lowercase.

Comment: I think the place to start is by understanding collations . . . https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE content <> upper(content)
```

That will only retrieve the rows that contain lower case characters.

Comment: Nice attempt but it is showing empty results..I have checked in my-sql .Please have a look again ...

Comment: @harshkumar why don't you show the actual query you're running?

Comment: I'm using query as you said : SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE content <>  UPPER(`content`) but not working for me .

Comment: Yes you are right Man Thanks !! I think it was Some issue in my local-host but online it's working...